# Microsoft Word 2010 opens with wrong template

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, templates

I am using my beloved MS Word 2010 on a Windows 10 PC. My problem is simple:

When I open Word, the blank doc does not use all of my settings, my template.

However, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, a new doc opens that does use my template.

I've confirmed that `Normal.dotm` is correct. I've made a change and re-saved it -- no change. I've changed to prompt on save of template -- no effect. I tried putting a shortcut to `normal.dotm` in the Startup folder, but just got an error, followed by the wrong template.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is your template named `normal.dotm` and saved in Word's template directory?

However, you can rename your template to `normal.dotm` and save it at this location:  `%AppData%\Microsoft\Templates\`. You can create a new document with your template and then save it at that location with the name `normal.dotm`. Set the type to Word Template.

If you want to start fresh, you can delete `normal.dotm` and the next time Word starts will create another `normal.dotm` with default properties. Then, you can modify it to suit your preferences, but save it to the same name and location as mentioned above.